# Multiple FileStreams for reading/writing different sections of same file concurrently in independent threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file-io

I have a large disk file (around 8 GB) containing several million records that I need to read, process in memory, and write back to another file. All the records are of a fixed length (say, 100 bytes).

I was thinking of parallelizing my process to run on multiple threads (typically 4–8), each of which would be (exclusively) assigned a particular section of the file to process (for example, 1 GB chunks). Since each thread would restrict its reads and writes to the section of the file it has been assigned, there is no risk of race hazards from my code.

Am I allowed to initialize multiple threads, each with its own `FileStream`, for reading from / writing to the same file without locking, without risking corruption? Assume that the target file has been expanded to its full size in advance (using `FileStream.SetLength`), and that the appropriate `FileShare` flag is specified when opening each `FileStream`.

Also, would I risk incurring slow-downs due to loss of buffering if multiple threads access the same file simultaneously? I am concerned about the “Detection of stream position changes” section in the MSDN documentation on the [`FileStream` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx), which states:

> When a `FileStream` object does not have an exclusive hold on its handle, another thread could access the file handle concurrently and change the position of the operating system's file pointer that is associated with the file handle. […]
>
> If an unexpected change in the handle position is detected in a call to the `Read` method, the .NET Framework discards the contents of the buffer and reads the stream from the file again. This can affect performance, depending on the size of the file and any other processes that could affect the position of the file stream.

Would this apply in my case, or are the file handles created by `FileStream` instances distinct and independent, even if accessing the same file?

Comment: do you have to preserve the order of records when writing to the target file?

Comment: How would you do the file partition if the file size is unknown? Your case might be that you know the file size (roughly), I am asking what if the file size is random?

Comment: @stt106: I wrote this question a while back. Nowadays, I'd probably go for dynamic scheduling in most cases -- for example, I'd populate a concurrent queue with placeholders for all 100MB chunks in the file, then let each thread pick the next chunk from the queue as soon as it finishes. If your process is I/O-bound, you should aim for large chunks to promote sequential disk access. Something similar to the "guided" scheduling strategy of OpenMP could potentially provide the best compromise between sequential access and load balancing at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly safe.

There is no risk of the problem mentioned in the MSDN article as it only applies if you make changes to underlying handle yourself. You are not accessing the handle at all.

You will notice random disk IO though which can destroy performance. You probably want to mitigate this by reading big chunks from the file (16MB or so) and using a lock to prevent concurrent Read and Write calls. Notice that you need to prevent concurrent calls even on different FileStream instances because IOs are not treated atomically by the OS. Internally they get split to small sizes to allow for fairness and predictable latency. This leads to random IO.

Why don't you just create one reader thread pushing buffers into a BlockingCollection? You can process that collection using Parallel.ForEach on multiple threads.

Comment: Good suggestion on reading large chunks to minimize random access. However, I believe that the smallest I/O access that the OS will split to is the sector size (e.g. 4096 bytes), correct? I’m trying to avoid `BlockingCollection` since I want to minimize locking as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, this is the smallest possible size and it is horrible. On my machine, I get 256KB chunks (measured with procmon and advanced output). This is *far* too small. In the time your disk does a single seek it could have read about 1MB! You don't want seeks.

Comment: Don't be afraid of locking. Locking 1000 times per second or so is nothing. By putting big chunks into the `BlockingCollection` you don't need to lock often.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I’ll take care to minimize the random access then and see whether I can switch my logic to use a `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: In the case of reading a large text file e.g. csv or txt; will `Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(path))` outperform processing the result of `File.ReadLines()` with a single thread? Since, as you said, hardware will still limit the parallel reading of the same file so multiple threads processing the result might even slow things down a bit?

Comment: @stt106 the file is not read in parallel. The single-threaded stream of lines will be processed in parallel. IO is not affected by this.

Answer (score 3):

"A memory-mapped file maps the contents of a file to an application’s logical address space. Memory-mapped files enable programmers to work with extremely large files because memory can be managed concurrently, and they allow complete, random access to a file without the need for seeking. Memory-mapped files can also be shared across multiple processes.

The CreateFromFile methods create a memory-mapped file from a specified path or a FileStream of an existing file on disk. Changes are automatically propagated to disk when the file is unmapped.

The CreateNew methods create a memory-mapped file that is not mapped to an existing file on disk; and are suitable for creating shared memory for interprocess communication (IPC).

A memory-mapped file is associated with a name.

You can create multiple views of the memory-mapped file, including views of parts of the file. You can map the same part of a file to more than one address to create concurrent memory. For two views to remain concurrent, they have to be created from the same memory-mapped file. Creating two file mappings of the same file with two views does not provide concurrency."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx

Comment: +1: Thanks for the suggestion; I had not considered `MemoryMappedFile`. However, I don’t think I’ll be able to use it for this specific problem since the size of the file exceeds the size of the available memory.

Comment: In any case mapped files will cause random IO in your particular case, reducing you to 2MB per sec and disk or so. Instead of 120MB/sec.

Comment: @douglas sorry you are underestimating the memory mapped files technique, I have seen practically >50 gb geo location files charting happening in 1-5 sec. Which was lagging when used regular file apis.. And over that u could have threading by having singles mm instance and multiple views and process as u wish. ;)

Comment: @HarshBaid: Thanks for the heads-up. I haven’t used `MemoryMappedFile`, so I can’t tell either way, but I’ll keep it in mind!